Bottom sheet backgroud in react native
I am using gorhom bottom-sheet, and I want the background to become gray when I open the bottom sheet. However, it doesn't work even though I followed the documentation.
Is there a prop or argument I need to add or something I might be missing?
   <BottomSheet
        ref={sheetRef}
        snapPoints={snapPoints}
        onCloseEnd={handleClosePress}
      >
        <BottomSheetView style={styles.modalContainer}>
        ////////some content
        </BottomSheetView>
      </BottomSheet>
  modalContainer: {
    width: "100%"
  },

the expected screen:

what i got:


I think you are talking about backdrop. You will need to provide a backdrop component with background style prop. See https://ui.gorhom.dev/components/bottom-sheet/components/bottomsheetbackdrop.
